# FilteredItemsSelectionDialog - refreshing content provider

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I have a filtered content selection dialog, and in the view menu  I have
checkboxes that adds an extra filter. It should function exactly like the "Show Derived Resources" check box of "Open Resource Selection Dialog" 'CTRL + SHIFT + R'.
I want the dialog to empty its content and re-call 'fillContentProvider().'

Is there any way to force the dialog to call 'fillContentProvider().'

I have tried the 'refresh()' method but it doesn't to what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to extend the ViewerFilter class, call it MyViewerFilter and over ride the method select() to suit our need.

Second: In the run() method of action call addListFilter(filter); where filter is an object of the typeMyViewerFilter than call scheduleRefresh();

Doing That will update the content provider with every click on the check box.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `refresh()` method will do what you want.

Comment: I am calling the applyFilter() in run() of action. And the applyFilter calls addElements() then it calls the the refresh(). What am I doing wrong. I might sound stupid, i must admit I am a complete beginner.